# How to exclude " and \ in ANTLR 4 string matching?

Tags: antlrworks, antlr4

I have the following string that I want to match against the rule, stringLiteral:

```
"D:\\Downloads\\Java\\MyFile"
```

And my grammar is the file: String.g4, as follows:

```
grammar String;

fragment
HexDigit : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

stringLiteral
    :  '"' ( EscapeSequence | XXXXX  )* '"'
    ;
fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UnicodeEscape
    |   OctalEscape
    ;

fragment
OctalEscape
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UnicodeEscape
    :   '\\' 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    ;
```

What should I put in the XXXXX location in order to match any character that is not \ or "?

I tried the following, and it all doesn't work:

```
~['\\'"']
~['\\'\"']
~["\]
~[\"\\]
~('\"'|'\\')
~[\\\"]
```

I am using ANTLRWorks 2 to try this out. Errors are the following:

```
D:\Downloads\ANTLR\String.g4 line 26:5 mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '"'
error(50): D:\Downloads\ANTLR\String.g4:26:5: syntax error: '<EOF>' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a character class, you only need to escape the backslash:

The following is **illegal**, it escapes the `]`:

```
[\]
```

The following matches a backslash:

```
[\\]
```

The following matches a quote:

```
["]
```

And the following matches either a backslash or quote:

```
[\\"]
```

In v4 style, your grammar could look like this:

```
grammar String;

/* other rules */

StringLiteral
    :  '"' ( EscapeSequence | ~[\\"]  )* '"'
    ;

fragment
HexDigit 
    : [0-9a-fA-F] 
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
    |   UnicodeEscape
    |   OctalEscape
    ;

fragment
OctalEscape
    :   '\\' [0-3] [0-7] [0-7]
    |   '\\' [0-7] [0-7]
    |   '\\' [0-7]
    ;

fragment
UnicodeEscape
    :   '\\' 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    ;
```

Note that you can't use fragments inside parser rules: `StringLiteral` must be a lexer rule!